# Empty collection after hibernate select

Tags: java, hibernate

I want find all records in table 'users' using hibernate but its allways return empty collection (im sure that some users are in db). My searching function looks like this:

```
    public List<Users> findAll() {
       DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Users.class);
       return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
    }
```

Why is not working?

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="format_sql">true</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intellidom</property>
  <property name="connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="connection.password"></property>

  <mapping file="mapping/Users.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Users.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="intellidom.entity.Users" table="users" schema="intellidom">
    <id column="id" name="id" type="int" >
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="login" column="login" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="password" column="password" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="firstName" column="firstName" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <property name="lastName" column="lastName" type="java.lang.String"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL?

Comment: @Genzotto i dont know how to get it, it should be in output when show_sql = true but it's not. criteria.toString() shows this: 'DetachableCriteria(CriteriaImpl(intellidom.entity.Users:this[][]))' but i think its not what you expected